# Select array entries by criteria

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, csv

I'm trying to write a conditional statement for fields from an imported CSV (data_dict), however, my current code using np.where does not seem to work. I am trying to find the age from (data_dict['Age']) of people depending on whether they are male or female, from (data_dict['Gender']). How would I approach solving this? Please see my code below. Many thanks.

Sample Data
Index,Age,Year,Crash_Month,Crash_Day,Crash_Time,Road_User,Gender,Crash_Type,Injury_Severity,Crash_LGA,Crash_Area_Type
1,37,2000,1,1,4:30:59,PEDESTRIAN,MALE,UNKNOWN,1,MARIBYRNONG,MELBOURNE
2,22,2000,1,1,0:07:35,DRIVER,MALE,ADJACENT DIRECTION,1,YARRA,MELBOURNE
3,47,2000,1,1,4:51:37,DRIVER,FEMALE,ADJACENT DIRECTION,0,YARRA,MELBOURNE
4,70,2000,1,1,4:27:56,DRIVER,MALE,ADJACENT DIRECTION,1,BANYULE,MELBOURNE

Expected Result
Age of Males: [37,22,70,...]
Age of Females: [47,...]

Current Result
Age of Males: []
Age of Females: []

```
gender1 = np.array(data_dict['Gender'])
age1 = np.array(data_dict['Age'])

age_females = age1[np.where(gender1 == 'Female')]
age_males = age1[np.where(gender1 == 'Male')]
```

Comment: Please provide an example show casing where the problem is and what is your expected output so that we can help.

Comment: How do you import your csv file? Is `data_dict` a dictionary?

Comment: @Ehsan imported using DictReader. And converted to np.array

Comment: Your code is fine as long as you import correctly. You also don't need `np.where`. `age_females = age1[gender1 == 'Female']` will also work. Would be better if you provide your data import code.